# A question on sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in R^2:x^2+y^4\leq 1\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\in R^2:x^4+y^6\leq 1\}$ be two subsets of $R^2$. Then

- $A\subseteq B$
- $B\subseteq A$
- None of these

I do not know how to start to prove or disprove anything. Further the regions given by sets are not much familiar to me except the thing I know that they both are convex regions and symmetric in opposite quadrants and are symmetrical about axes.

Comment: You might want to find a better title, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=\{(x,y)\in R^2:x^2+y^4\leq 1\}$$ and $$B=\{(x,y)\in R^2:x^4+y^6\leq 1\}$$

As $x,y\in\mathbb R$, we have $x^2\ge0$ and $y^4\ge0$.

In $A$,
$$x^2+y^4\le1$$

Thus,
$$0\le x^4\le x^2\le 1$$
$$0\le y^6\le y^4\le 1$$

which results in
$$x^4+y^6\le x^2+y^4\le 1$$

Thus, for every $(x,y)\in A$, $(x,y)\in B$.

Hence, $$A\subseteq B$$.

Comment: thanks GoodDeed...great work.